# Copying specific range of data from one workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy data from a workbook and paste it to another.
I want it to copy a specific range, up to the last cell that contains data.

This is what I have so far but it gives me a 'subscript out of range' error.

```
Sub BackLog()

With Workbooks("Backlog Query AHSI").Worksheets("Sheet1")
   lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Value = Workbooks("Backlog Query AHSI").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Value
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("L2:L" & lastRow).Value = Workbooks("Backlog Query AHSI").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("X2:X" & lastRow).Value
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("M2:AH" & lastRow).Value = Workbooks("Backlog Query AHSI").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L2:AG" & lastRow).Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line gives the error?

Comment: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Value = Workbooks("Order Query AHSI").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Value

Comment: What is value of `lastRow` at that point?

Comment: @El Ronnoco it's 1245

Comment: Do you have a Worksheet named `Data` in current workbook?

Comment: In fact you are looking in `Backlog Query AHSI` for last row and then pulling from `Order Query AHSI`

Comment: ah... I had a typo in the sheet name. Accidentally typed "Daata".

Comment: That was a really stupid mistake.. I was looking at my code for so long wondering what was wrong with it >.> It works now. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use **Copy** you need only specify a single cell for the destination:

```
Workbooks("Order Query AHSI").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("A2")
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Which line gives the error?**
>   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Value =
>   Workbooks("Order Query AHSI").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" &
>   lastRow).Value – user3324221 14 mins ago
>
> **What is value of lastRow at that point?** 
>   it's 1245
>
> **Do you have a Worksheet named Data in current workbook?**     ah... I had a typo in the sheet name. Accidentally typed "Daata".

I always find the VBA error 'Subscript out of Range' sends me down the wrong track as it immediately makes me look for a numeric subscript being out of range. However in this case it's just that the named Sheet cannot be found.